# Arel query issues using where and group

Tags: activerecord

In Rails 4, I have these 3 tables:

Users table with these columns:
-name
-email

Orders table with these columns:
-amount
-user_id

Items table with these columns:
-name
-description

OrderItems table with these columns:
order_id
item_id

Relations:
-The orderItems table is a joined table
-The user has many orders and an order belongs to a user.

Questions:
1) Find the 5 biggest orders (orders with the most items)
I think the query is:

```
OrderItem.group(:order_id).order(count(id) desc").limit(5).pluck(:order_id)
```

What is the group exactly doing? When I type in `OrderItem.group(:order_id)` only I Don't understand the output.

2) How do I find a user with the name "betty" AND "the email "betty@gmail.com". For this, do I need to write SQL inside my Arel?

Answer (score 0):

1. `OrderItem.group(:order_id)` by itself won't produce valid SQL.  `group` turns into an SQL `GROUP BY` statement which groups rows together if they share the same value for the column that is specified.  `GROUP BY` needs to be used with a `SELECT` statement that has the columns that were in the `GROUP BY` or that are aggregate functions like `COUNT`.

   Your full query is missing a quotation mark in the `order` clause.  You'll want:

   ```
   OrderItem.group(:order_id).order("count(id) desc").limit(5).pluck(:order_id)
   ```
2. To find a user with the name "betty" and the email "betty@gmail.com" you can use:

   ```
   User.where(name: "betty", email: "betty@gmail.com")
   ```